# Passing an argument to a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a `<div>` which is clickable. Code:

```
<div
    onclick="clicked(this);"
    class="green-column"
    id="infoblock"
    data-type="<?php echo $descriptions[description];?>">
        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</div>
```

I need to display `$descriptions[description]` as a pop up message to the user without using JavaScript `alert()`. I tried to use `Modal` but couldn't find a way to pass a message to it. Could any one please help me in this?

Comment: What do you mean by *without using Javascript*? `clicked()` is a Javascript function.

Comment: Sorry..was thinking something else while typing.. :) edited it..!!

Comment: Mine ans will work for you

Comment: yes.it works..but i need to do it without alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery then why use `onclick`? You can build your dialog on the fly!

Markup:

```html
<div class="green-column infoblock" data-type="description1">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</div>
<div class="green-column infoblock" data-type="description2">
    <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(".infoblock").click(function() {
        $("<div>" + $(this).attr("data-type") + "</div>").dialog();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/nm6kj/)**

Comment: Exactly what I wanted..thanks a lot, but i have more that one div with the same id, so its not working. will find work around. Thanks a lot..

Comment: You're welcome. You can't have more than one element with the same ID. It's invalid html. What you need to do is to change id to class. See updated answer.

Comment: If you use id as a selector for a click handler you'll end up with a lot of handlers: e.g. `$("#infoblock1").click(...);`, `$("#infoblock2").click(...);` etc. Use class instead. I updated the answer and jsfiddle to show that.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am using the class to handle the clicks now. But the dialog function doesn't seem to be working with arguments, for example : `dialog({ 
                 modal: true,
                 buttons: {
                  Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                  }
                 }
             });`                                                           doesn't give me the proper output. :( can u point out any mistake here..?

Comment: You missed square brackets for buttons array in dialog parameters. I've updated jsfiddle for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div
    onclick="clicked(this);"
    class="green-column"
    id="infoblock"
    data-type="<?php echo $descriptions[description];?>">
        <i class="icon-ok"></i>
</div>

<div id="example"></div>

function clicked(desc) {
    $('#example').html(desc);
    $('#example').html(desc).dialog();
}
```